# how to reinsert old records from excel file in salesforce production edition

Tags: data-loader, user-record

I have old records and i want to reinsert it now.

i having a contacts and their spendings

e.g
like by year  2006- abc
                      2007 -abc

**now i want to add 2005 records from excel sheet.**

and excel sheet having acc name,accid,contact name,cotanct id and monthwise data like  jan to dec.

what will be the best approach?
Please help...

Answer (score 2):

As I understand probably those object exist in system and are connected to other data?
In this case best way will be export existing data (for example using Data loader)and match records based on excel(VLOOKUP is most useful! :)) file and file  from salesforce.
After that you should create CSV file with Id of object and new value of field and just update those objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Data Loader to insert records into your org. Once logged into Salesforce go to Setup -> Data Loader to download the PC version. You can get a Mac version [here](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/lexiloader/) as well. If you want to insert the records with their historical dates check out [this blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/27/modifying-salesforcecom-system-fields/).